# text field with format xx/xx/xx

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

i've a text field and the format must xx/xx/xx. xx it's a number from 1 to 9 and each number correspond to a different type of runway contamination for the 1/3,2/3  and 3/3 of it's lenght. (i.e. 1 dry, 2 wet, 3 snow).I can also have 2 digit (ie 32) in which case it means that it's snow over wet.
 I want to get this number from the text field, convert it into plain text and set a label but I don't know how to get rid of the slashes when I get the string.... any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`:

```
NSString *trimmedString = [textFieldString
       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];
```

Or, if you want to break it up into 3 parts:

```
NSArray *components = [textFieldString
                     componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
for (NSString *component in components) {


}
```